# Sharepoint 2013 Workflows - Create task without disapprove option

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I need to create a task in Sharepoint Designer 2013 on my workflow. But I need to create only with "complete task" option. When I am creating the task, there are two options: approve and disapprove.

These tasks don't make sense to disapprove, I just need to select the option to complete and finish the task.

Is there any option in SP Designer 2013 that can help me?

Comment: Hi, Di u get ur answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to Remove the Reject Button from **Task Outcome column**.

Go to site settings->site columns->find “Task Outcome” column
[image]

And Save. Now You Will Get Only Approve Button on from your Task.
[image]
As you Can see there is no **Reject** Button in this Assigned Task.